# How does a quantum repeater work without violating the no cloning theorem?

Tags: quantum-information

Quantum repeaters work similar to classical repeaters to allow a qubit to be successfully communicated a longer distance before it is overwhelmed by noise.  There is significant  discussion of this on the WWW and in the published literature.  Recently, actual working models have been claimed on arXiv: here is one example: https://arxiv.org/abs/1811.10723.

How do these quantum repeaters avoid  violating  the no cloning theorem?  Can they be linked to provide essentially unlimited distance transmission of a qubit?  (analogous to a classical repeater with a classical bit?)

(This post has been  re-edited to be more comprehensible at the request of the moderators. If it is still unclear, I will need help in clarifying it further.)

Comment: Why would it?  .

Comment: State transfer $\neq$ state cloning, similar to the way that cutting and pasting is different from copying and pasting.

Comment: It's currently unclear what exactly this question is asking without clicking on the link you provided. To make questions more accessible and guard against [link rot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot), please include all relevant information, such as the explanation of notation or specific terminology used, in your question.

Comment: @KyleKanos I disagree both with the fact that the link helps to understand the question and that it is bad practice to link to the arxive (personally, I would be more worried that links to SE would become unavailable).

Comment: @NorbertSchuch in its original form, also when the comment was made, the question was "here's a paper, how does X not happen" which is unclear without having read the paper. The comment you see is an automated one that I, skiing others, inserted in many such situations.

Comment: @KyleKanos The concept of quantum repeaters are around for about 20 years.  It is unclear what this specific paper adds to the question. -- Well, if it is an automated comment, it is less surprising that it does not apply.

Comment: @JimGraber The edit doesn't help to clarify what's unclear: Why would you think that repeaters would violate no-cloning? Could you elaborate? (And why did you ask a second, seemingly completely unrelated, question?)

Comment: @Norbert Schuch  OK I try again: By the way, the answers and the other questions that popped up when I searched for my question have been very helpful.

Comment: For an expert in QM, I guess it is clear that the repeater does not clone.  But I think that the naive expectation is that a repeater does clone.  The no cloning theorem is apparently "saved" because a repeater destroys the original to create the farther away copy.

Comment: @JimGraber Do you understand why teleportation does not clone?

Comment: The more general topic I am trying to understand is the limitatioms on quantum repeaters and  quantum communication in general.  In particular, physical as opposed to mathematiical implementations.  Thanks for your cosideration

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87118/discussion-between-jim-graber-and-norbert-schuch).

Answer (score 4):

In quantum mechanics, a measurement will not disturb the system if the system is already in an eigenstate of the obserable being measured.

The "No cloning" theorem is the assertion that there is no physical process $U$ that can achieve
$$
U \left(| \psi \rangle | 0 \rangle \right) = | \psi \rangle | \psi \rangle
\;\;\;\;\; \forall \; | \psi \rangle
$$
but **note the crucial FOR ALL part**. It means you can't have a process which takes as input an unknown state, and gives as output two copies of that state, no matter what state it was.

A *quantum repeater* is doing a different job. It is a device used to set up one specific, known, entangled state between two places $A$, $B$. Once this is done then the situation can be used to pass a general unknown state $\psi$ from one place to another. The word 'repeater' here is only loosely comparable to its use in classical communication channels, but it is reasonably fair; it alludes to the part of the process where the entangled state is set up. This is done using methods such as entanglement swapping. If you have an intermediate place $C$ in between $A$ and $B$, then an entanglement between $A$ and $C$ can be combined with one between $C$ and $B$ to produce the one you want between $A$ and $B$. But note, this does not involve copying some general state, it involves producing one specific state.

After that the channel can be put into action, and the evolution is
$$
R \left( |\psi, \;A \rangle | |0, \;B \rangle |\right) = |0, \;A \rangle| \psi,\; B \rangle 
$$
where $\psi$ refers to a quantum state such as the state of a qubit, and $A$, $B$ refer to different physical locations, such as different cities on Earth. As you see, no copying is involved.

Comment: Isn't a repeater a device which builds up entanglement over long distances by doing entanglement swapping on entangled states generated over shorter distances, rather than teleporting an unknown state as your $R$ does?

Comment: I see what you mean. I was regarding that part as a sort of done deal, and then putting the repeater into action on a general unknown state, to show that it is not cloning. However, I will edit my answer to make it more complete.